# Issue with Pear Net_URL_Mapper

Tags: php, routes, pear

I started working on a project which uses Net_URL_Mapper from PEAR (php) as the router. For some reason URLS like the following seem to create a problem to the package classes. Think it's a bug but not sure (haven't looked around for it yet).

example URL : /login/?q=somevalue

Sample code

```
$m->connect('/login/:action/', array('control' => 'login','action'=>'default'));
```

The question is: have u used Net_URL_Mapper and had this problem? Did you solve it? Am i doing something wrong with the above path?

Is there an other routing package (or framework) which you could suggest that is simple (low learning curve) and could easily replace net_url_mapper without much trouble (requiring too many changes) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$m->connect('/login/:action/', 
    array('control' => 'login','action'=>'default'));
```

Would expect a url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/login/someaction/?q=somevarible
```

Following would route to the action **default**

```
http://www.example.com/login/
```

This would route to controller **login**, action **opinid** and it would pass *username* **Foo** as $_Get variable

```
http://www.example.com/login/openid/?username=Foo
```